# Ajax: form data not passing on to e-mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my form:

```
  <form id='forma' action="index1.php" method="post">          
      <input name="name1" type="text">          

      <input class="s_submit" value="ЗАКАЗАТЬ" type="button" onclick="send1()">
  </form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function send1(){
$('#forma').submit(function(event){
    var formData = {
        'fio'               : $('input[name=name1]').val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'post', 
        url         : 'index1.php', 
        data        : formData, 
        dataType    : 'json', 
        encode      : true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data); 
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
}
```

This is my index1.php:

```
 $fio=$_POST['name1'];

 $mail_to="_______my_email_________";
 $msg="Your name is: $fio

 mail($mail_to, $thm, $msg, $headers);
```

On my e-mail only "Your name is:" message is sent, without the name someone submitted. Code works as expected when I set input type to **submit** and get rid entirely of **send1()** function. But input must be the *button* type and never go to another page on press. I suppose I should get rid of some of variable assignments, but which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable in the POST data is defined in `formData` object with the key of `fio`. Your PHP to retrieve it should therefore be:

```
$fio = $_POST['fio'];
```

Answer (score 0):

On the form submission, you are overriding the actual form (containing your text field) from being submitted, and submitting your own formData object.

You can quite easily get the data from your HTML form by using

```
    $("#forma").serializeArray()
```